# Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Avatar' in 'D:\own_files\ReactTutorial\react-app\src'

Tags: reactjs

Hi I just started my first application with React. I'm using a simple login component, and after I use npm start it throws this error: Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Avatar' in 'D:\own_files\ReactTutorial\react-app\src'

I have basic React code

Here's my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import GoodBye from './GoodBye';
import Hello from './Hello';
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar';
import LoginComponent from './LoginComponent';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <NavigationBar />
                    <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
                    <Route path="/goodbye" component={GoodBye} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

And my LoginComponent:

```
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

function Copyright() {
    return (
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
            {'Copyright © '}
            <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
                Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
            {new Date().getFullYear()}
            {'.'}
        </Typography>
    );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));

export default function SignIn() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                    <LockOutlinedIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                    Sign in
        </Typography>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="email"
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        autoComplete="email"
                        autoFocus
                    />
                    <TextField
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                    />
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                        label="Remember me"
                    />
                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        fullWidth
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.submit}
                    >
                        Sign In
          </Button>
                    <Grid container>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                Forgot password?
              </Link>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </div>
            <Box mt={8}>
                <Copyright />
            </Box>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you install Material-UI?

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

or use a CDN?

https://material-ui.com/

Comment: I forgot it good point, but now I get this error: Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined i need to install icons too right?

Comment: Yes, that should take care of that. npm install @material-ui/icons
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 1):

> `Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Add' in 'E:\reacttut\awesomeapp\src'`

I was facing same issue. Then I used:

```js
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
```

instead of

```js
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Following Lines to your **package.json** "dependencies"

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.10.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
```

and execute command **yarn install** or **npm install**